# How to add an image upload field to a node programmatically?

Tags: entities, 6

I want to add an image upload field to a node programmatically when the node is being loaded.

I heard that you could use hook_form_alter() but I am looking for better options. Could anyone provide a solution?

Comment: just to confirm are you on drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: are you looking adding the field or adding an image it self? do you have a field associated with the content type?

Comment: I am using drupal 6 :-). I am  looking to add an image upload field so that users can see the image uploaded using the field in the teaser view.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CCK [imagefield](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) to the node.

If you need to show / hide it, use your form_alter to set `['#access'] = FALSE` on the field.